# Retrieving subject names based on color

Tags: c#, .net

I have a table which is named as `Subject`. It has 2 columns `COLOR` and `SUBJECT`. The color is basically an integer value.

The table filled with sample data.

```
Color       Subject

1            C#
2            Java
3            Python
4            C++
5            Operating Systems
6            DBMS
4            C
6            Ruby
```

I am assigning colors for the above subjects in order to generate a time-table. From the table we can see that some of the subjects have repeated colors, it means that those two subjects can be handled at the same hour.

My question is, how can i access the Subject names when i scan through the colors using a while loop with the `Read()` operation.

Can a user defined function can be devised for this operation?

Thank you.

EDIT : Since I don't have an idea to proceed with, this is what I have done so far.

```
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand get = new SqlCommand("select * from Color_Subjects",con);
            SqlDataReader read = get.ExecuteReader();

            while (read.Read())
            {
                colors.Add((int)read.GetValue(1));
                subjects.Add(read.GetString(0));
            }

            int colcount = colors.Count();
            int subcount = subjects.Count();
```

I have basically copied the values from the database into two lists.

I need to insert the subjects with the different color to a unique time slot (for creating a time table) and the subjects with the different color to the same time slot.

Is this approach correct or is there an better approach in order to perform the operation?

Comment: @Hakunamatata I have edited my post with my work so far

Comment: @Prithvi Why not create a class called Subject and add two properties to it for name and color and create a list of Subjects instead of two separate lists. That way you can use that list to get subjects associated with color.

Comment: @Hakunamatata could you please explain with a sample of code?

Comment: It would be simple enough to create a List based on the database values and then simply look up the appropriate value from the List. You only need one list here, mapped either on Color or on Subject, depending on your purpose.

Comment: @ManoDestra could you suggest a different approach other than the list of there is any? I operation I have to perform is, I have go insert the subjects with the different color to a unique time-slot (in the database) and the subjects with the same color to the same time-slot (as of the subject with the same color). Is my approach correct or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class called Subject

```
public class Subject 
{
    public string SubjectName {get;set;}
    public int Color {get;set;}
}
```

Read data from your database and add values to List of subjects

```
con.Open();
            SqlCommand get = new SqlCommand("select * from Color_Subjects",con);
            SqlDataReader read = get.ExecuteReader();

          List<Subject> subjects = new List<Subject>(); // Declare a list of subjects
            while (read.Read())
            {
                subjects.Add(new Subject(){ SubjectName=read.GetString(0),
                                             Color=((int)read.GetValue(1)) } );
            }
    //Get All Unique Colors
        List<int> allColors = subjects.Select(x=>x.Color).Distinct().ToList();

        //Iterate through each color and get subjects associated with that color
        foreach(int thisColor in allColors)
        {
            List<Subject> subjectsForThisColor = subjects.Where(x=>x.Color==thisColor).ToList();
            // Output to console -- 
            foreach(Subject s in subjectsForThisColor)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s.SubjectName + " - " + s.Color);
            }
        }
```

Note : I haven't compile above code so there may be syntax error.

Comment: I have tried this and It is close to what I was supposed to get. But, There is a repetition of the subject names. i.e, in the output I am getting C# - 1 twice and similarly for all the subjects. Is there a way to get the subject names only once?